# How to convert a csv to json with first column as key, and second one as value using jsonlite or other package?

Tags: r, json

How to convert a csv to json with first column as key, and second one as value using jsonlite or other package?

Now:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "full": "CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS",
>     "abb": "CA-CANCER J CLIN"
>   },
>   {
>     "full": "NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY",
>     "abb": "NAT REV MOL CELL BIO"
>   }
> ```

Expect:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS": "CA-CANCER J CLIN",
>      },
>   {
>     "NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY": "NAT REV MOL CELL BIO"
>       }
> ]
> ```

MWE:

```
abb <- structure(list(full = c("CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS", "NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY"), abb = c("CA-CANCER J CLIN", "NAT REV MOL CELL BIO")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))

abb|> 
     jsonlite::toJSON(pretty=TRUE)
```

Thanks for any idea!

If any other package available, it also ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toJSON(setNames(as.list(abb$abb), abb$full), pretty = T)


{
  "CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS": ["CA-CANCER J CLIN"],
  "NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY": ["NAT REV MOL CELL BIO"]
}
```

or to have the unboxed version like you showed in the desired result use:

```
toJSON(setNames(as.list(abb$abb), abb$full), pretty = T, auto_unbox = T)

{
  "CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS": "CA-CANCER J CLIN",
  "NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY": "NAT REV MOL CELL BIO"
}
```

and if you really want the outer box in the output, wrap it in a list like this:

```
toJSON(list(setNames(as.list(abb$abb), abb$full)), pretty = T, auto_unbox = T)

[
  {
    "CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS": "CA-CANCER J CLIN",
    "NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY": "NAT REV MOL CELL BIO"
  }
]
```

Comment: the 2nd solution is is what I want， many thanks.